# SQL where clause for self-referencing table

Tags: sql-server

I have something like the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](450) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [Created] [datetime] NULL,
    [OrgId] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [FK_Test_OrgId] FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Test(Id),

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
```

A new entry has `OrgId = null`. If an entry has been edited, a new row is created with `OrgId` set to its original parent. If an entry is edited multiple times, all children will have `OrgId` set to the Id of the original row. The created datetime provides the "order".

What I need to do is select only the newest versions.

Given the table below, I am looking to select only Id 3, 5 & 6

```
Id  Title   Description          Created        PreId
-----------------------------------------------------
1   Car     Orginal car          2014-01-01     NULL
2   House   Original house       2014-01-01     NULL
3   Bike    Original bike        2014-01-01     NULL
4   Car     Car updated          2014-06-01     1
5   Car     Car updated again    2014-08-01     1
6   House   house updated        2014-09-01     2
```

Any input appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Check for hierarchical queries using CTEs and consider changing PreId to a `hierarchyid`

Comment: 'Original spouse'  missing ;-)

Comment: I would suggest to create a `ValidThrough` column to be updated every time you create a new child entry, so would be easier to find the current valid data with a simple `BETWEEN` clause

Comment: Sounds interesting,  could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I understood you create a new entry every time you get it updated, keeping the old values for some logging propose, so to get you latest values in the suggested approach you could do something like `SELECT * FROM Test WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN Created and ValidThrough` without using any features like `MAX` or `TOP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all records are pointing at the original row (and not the previous one) :

```
SELECT ID, Title, DEscription, CREATED, PreID 
FROM
  (SELECT ID, Title, DEscription, CREATED, PreID, 
  ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ISNULL(OrgID,id) order by id desc) rn 
  FROM test) A
where RN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the above solution returns all rows except Id 4 for me.

Comment: But, if I remove the ISNULL part then i get the result-set i am looking for :)

Comment: @Henrik you should need a `ISNULL`part. i dont know why Amir multiplies the id with -1  correct would be `ISNULL(OrgID,Id)`

Comment: Correct. I was too hasty to conclude it wasnt needed.

Comment: You are right about the -1. I removed it.. The is null is so to group the original records with the new versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Titles AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT Title
  FROM dbo.Test
)
SELECT A.ID, Ti.Title, A.[Description], A.Created, A.OrgId
FROM Titles AS Ti
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) ID, [Description], [Created], [OrgId]
             FROM dbo.Test AS Te
             WHERE Te.Title = Ti.Title
             ORDER BY Created DESC
            ) AS A;
```

Comment: This solution should perform well for high-density-cases and if you have the right index to support the query. High-Density means there are few DISTINCT Titles in comparison to the number of rows in the tables. If there are many DISTINCT Titles the ROW_NUMBER-Approach should work better.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but is solution is based on Titles being the same, which they not necessarily are (I can see how one could assume they are based on my simple example). Titles can change as well as description.

Comment: oh i see :-) Thanks for the response